# Silverlight - Saving an already downloaded image to disk

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a silverlight application that displays images. These images display fine but I would like to go one step further and let people save an image to disk.

*I don't want to redownload the image using the WebClient class.*

I can see the image so I know it's already cached somewhere on my computer. Technically, I don't think it should be necessary to open any new connections...

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can Render your image into a WritableBitmap, encode it using one of the free encoders available (like ImageTools) and save it to disk using SaveFileDialog. The only other choice is to load image using WebClient. If you want to avoid loading image twice you could load it with WebClient from the start.